# Sammy.js with google analytics in knockout app

Tags: knockout.js, google-analytics, sammy.js

I am using knockout with sammy.js for my web application. And I am trying to add google analytics to it. I quickly found the [following plugin](https://github.com/britg/sammy-google-analytics) to implement page tracking.

I followed the steps and my page looks like this:

```
<script src="jquery, knockout, other things, sammy, sammy.googleanalytics"></script> // I list them this way just to save space here
```

My main javascript file looks like this:

```
Sammy(function(){
    this.use(Sammy.GoogleAnalytics);

    // all my routes
    this.get('#!route1', function(){

    });
}).run();
```

And then follows Google analytics script

```
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
    (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'myTrackingNumber', 'myURL');
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

When I run the application and navigate through different routes, I see not errors in the console, but I also see no communication to google analytics server: nothing like this `http://www.google-analytics.com/__utm.gif?` is shown in network tab in chrome (even during the page load).

Viewing example page in sammy.js/google-analitcs I see that their [GA code is different](http://britg.github.io/sammy-google-analytics/#/bar). Also I see that the latest commit to the plugin is like 4 years ago, so most probably it is outdated.

How can I make my GA work with knockout and sammy?

Comment: The linked plugin is using the old version of the analytics API. However the plugin is very small and easy to update: https://gist.github.com/nemesv/1d03ab62ca791a579b8b  I'm not able to test this so please try it and if it's working I will add it as an anwser

Comment: @nemesv thank you very much for looking into the problem. I tried your update but it still does not work. Only during the first load it sends information to google server and after this nothing happens when I navigate to other states.

Comment: Are you starting the Sammy application on the DOM ready? So the `.run()` should be executed when the whole page including the analitycs gets loaded.

Comment: @nemesv No, my app starts when google analytics is loaded, but I have not bound it to `domready`. Thanks for clarifying it. I am sorry, but I am not able to test it right now. In few hours I will write you a proper response. Really thank you for looking into my problem.

Comment: It seems it is not related to the DOM ready but how the new analytics works and it overrides the `ga` function when the analitics script is loaded asynchronously. So I've updated the plugin on the gist to handle this: https://gist.github.com/nemesv/1d03ab62ca791a579b8b. This version should work now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Google analytics snippet is using [Analytics.js](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/) which is

> a new way to measure how users interact with your website. It is similar to the previous tracking code, `ga.js`, but offers more flexibility for developers to customize their implementations.

So the API has been changed since the `ga.js` which was used by the [sammy-google-analytics](https://github.com/britg/sammy-google-analytics) plugin.

When you are using the `Analytics.j` you need to use the new [`ga` function](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/pages) instead of the old `pageTracker` object.

Luckily the plugin is very simple and there is only two places where you need to change it use the new API:

```
(function ($) {

  Sammy = Sammy || {};

  // A simple plugin that pings Google Analytics tracker
  // every time a route is triggered
  //
  // === Arguments
  //
  // +trackerAccessor+:: an accessor for the Google Analytics ga function.  
  // Defaults to the default function defined by the analytics.js snippet, 
  // or pass your own tracker accessor function if you
  // have a custom install
  Sammy.GoogleAnalytics = function (app, trackerAccessor) {
      var _trackerAccessor = 
            trackerAccessor || function () { return window.ga; },
        shouldTrack = true;

      this.helpers({
          noTrack: function () {
              disableTracking();
          }
      });

      this.bind('event-context-after', function () {
          if (typeof _trackerAccessor != 'undefined' && _trackerAccessor() 
                     && shouldTrack) {
              console.log('tracking', this.path);
              _trackerAccessor()('send', 'pageview', this.path);
          }
          enableTracking();
      });

      function disableTracking() {
          shouldTrack = false;
      }

      function enableTracking() {
          shouldTrack = true;
      }
  };
})(jQuery);
```

The rest of the plugin should work the same as described in [its documentation:](https://github.com/britg/sammy-google-analytics).